# Is it possible to grant Full Trust to url within Medium Trust Web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, aspose, medium-trust

I'm using Dlls (Cells & PDF) from Aspose and ran into permission issue because the site must be set to Medium Trust while the DLLs requires Full Trust.  I have attempted to different method to grant full trust to the DLLs while the site remains in Medium Trust.  So far, I've tried the following:
Created a separate custom medium trust config file with the code group for

```
<CodeGroup
   class="UnionCodeGroup"
       version="1"
       PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
       Name="Aspose.PDF_Asp.Net"
       Description="This code group grant full trust to Aspose.PDF">
       <IMembershipCondition
            class="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
            version="1"        
PublicKeyBlob="00240......."/>
</CodeGroup>
```

I've also tried adding to the web.config under the .Net Framework Config folder
under the

```
<fullTrustAssemblies>
<add
   assemblyName="Aspose.Pdf"
   version="10.6.0.0"
   publicKey="00240000......"
/>
```

So far, none of these methods worked.  So I'm wondering if it's possible to grant full trust to a specific page within the site without using a webservice. If I have a page that I can pass arguments and use that to run under Full Trust then I can mitigate at least this issue of Aspose not working under Medium Trust.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing the Aspose (Cells and PDF) assemblies in GAC (Global Assembly Cache). If I am not mistaken then installing any assembly in GAC grants it Full Trust permissions automatically and therefore it should resolve your issue.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: I tried that and it does not work. This issue is also being posted on Aspose.Cells forum at http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/652593/aspese.cell/showthread.aspx#652593.

Comment: I will look into this issue and update you on the forum.

Comment: Please check the updates at these posts on the forum: ( http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/653341/653341/showthread.aspx#653341 ) and ( http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/653341/654005/showthread.aspx#654005 )

Comment: I was able to replicate this issue by running your sample project provided in the forum and logged this issue in our database for a fix. Please check this post for your reference (http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/653341/654123/showthread.aspx#654123)

Comment: To update you further, We actually removed the codes "[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]" in order to pass APTCA check of Binscope. We will add  "[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]" back in order to make Aspose.Cells run in the Medium Trust environment. 

Once the fix is available, we will let you know on the forum. Please check (http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/654786/654786/showthread.aspx#654786)

Comment: This issue has been resolved in Aspose.Cells v8.5.2.4 or greater as you have also confirmed it in the forum.

Comment: Thanks. We were able to get the server to run the app in Full Trust.  I will have to try the new version if we ever have to change our trust level.